# Ejabberd: Xmpp messages get dropped if sent before client's resume_timeout

Tags: android, tcp, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I've recently compiled latest ejabberd code from github on my Arch linux machine. I'm new to ejabberd so I may have made a newbie mistake.

I'm facing an issue where in a particular scenario packets do not reach the target client. This happens if the message is sent **after** client gets disconnected but **before** client's session is closed due to resume_timeout.

I've followed instructions as mentioned over here https://www.ejabberd.im/faq/tcp , but still I've been unable to handle all cases.

The relevant parts of my ejabberd.yml look like

```
listen:
  - 
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    resend_on_timeout: true
    resume_timeout: 60
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s

  - 
    ## Not sure if resend_on_timeout is required here
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    resend_on_timeout: true
    resume_timeout: 60
    http_bind: true

modules:
  ...
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping:
    send_pings: true
    ping_interval: 60
    timeout_action: kill
```

Here's the output of ejabberd log corresponding to client's acitivites:

1. Client A disconnects uncleanly

   ```
   2016-06-19 10:59:51.369 [info] <0.549.0>@ejabberd_c2s:fsm_next_state:2454 Waiting for resumption of stream for 9739937980@gappi.in/Smack`
   ```
2. Client B Logs in and sends a message to A

   ```
   2016-06-19 11:00:00.320 [info] <0.510.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:333 (#Port<0.19876>) Accepted connection 139.162.34.247:41186 -> 139.162.34.247:5222
   2016-06-19 11:00:00.575 [info] <0.559.0>@ejabberd_c2s:wait_for_sasl_response:900 ({socket_state,fast_tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.19876>,#Port<0.19877>},<0.558.0>}) Accepted authentication for echo by undefined from 137
   2016-06-19 11:00:00.715 [info] <0.559.0>@ejabberd_c2s:open_session:1111 ({socket_state,fast_tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.19876>,#Port<0.19877>},<0.558.0>}) Opened session for echo@gappi.in/13353511976792329881266
   2016-06-19 11:00:00.776 [info] <0.559.0>@ejabberd_c2s:handle_enable:2700 Stream management with resumption enabled for echo@gappi.in/13353511976792329881266
   2016-06-19 11:00:00.984 [info] <0.559.0>@ejabberd_c2s:terminate:1778 ({socket_state,fast_tls,{tlssock,#Port<0.19876>,#Port<0.19877>},<0.558.0>}) Close session for echo@gappi.in/13353511976792329881266
   ```
3. Client A session is finally closed due to resume_timeout

   ```
   2016-06-19 11:00:51.370 [info] <0.549.0>@ejabberd_c2s:terminate:1778 ({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.19869>,<0.548.0>}) Close session for 9739937980@gappi.in/Smack
   ```
4. Client A logs back in

   ```
   2016-06-19 11:01:14.078 [info] <0.510.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:333 (#Port<0.19879>) Accepted connection 122.172.241.21:26597 -> 139.162.34.247:5222
   2016-06-19 11:01:14.707 [info] <0.566.0>@ejabberd_c2s:wait_for_sasl_response:900 ({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.19879>,<0.565.0>}) Accepted authentication for 9739937980 by undefined from 122.172.241.21
   2016-06-19 11:01:14.868 [info] <0.566.0>@ejabberd_c2s:open_session:1111 ({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.19879>,<0.565.0>}) Opened session for 9739937980@gappi.in/Smack
   2016-06-19 11:01:14.966 [info] <0.566.0>@ejabberd_c2s:handle_enable:2700 Stream management with resumption enabled for 9739937980@gappi.in/Smack
   ```

As per this guide, https://www.ejabberd.im/faq/tcp, after the resume_timeout expires, the unacked messages should have been handled by mod_offline. But this is not happening.

Result : No message reaches client.

Any pointers?

Comment: Did u tried reducing resume_timeout timeout. Let's try changing it to 20 or set ping_interval to greater than 60.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to a bug in Ejabberd  https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/1160 which has been fixed now.